# Unchecking radio buttons with jQuery a little buggy

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a need to be able to uncheck the checked radio button in a set of 3. It works for the most part, but it's a little buggy - sometimes unchecking when I want to check a different button, sometimes not checking a button on the first click when I've unchecked a different one, unchecking after a clicking different radios a few times, etc. Hopefully someone can take a look and see what's causing this

The CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {   display: none;  }
input[type="radio"] + label {
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(../images/check_radio_sheet.png) -57px top no-repeat;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="optionsfilter" action="#">
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li>
<span style="color: #eee;">Smoking Inside?</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
<input type="radio" name="smokingoption" id="smoking" value="smoking"><label for="smoking" onclick=""><span></span>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="smokingoption" id="non-smoking" value="non-smoking"><label for="non-smoking" onclick=""><span></span>No</label>
<input type="radio" name="smokingoption" id="cigarsmoking" value="cigar"><label for="cigarsmoking" onclick=""><span></span>Cigars</label>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Here's the script:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    if(checked){
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } else{
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

And here's a jsFiddle with all the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/RfDk6/

Comment: Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/RfDk6/2/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Isn't this default behavior of radio buttons?

Comment: @DON that just gives the default behavior for radio buttons.  I'm using these as an option in a filter, but I want the user to be able to uncheck completely to remove the option from the filter if they want to. Since these 3 go together, I need to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, the code I posted unchecks the checked radio button leaving none of them checked. As I stated in my question, it's buggy and I need it to behave as expected, but I don't see what's causing the unwanted behavior

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but as of jQuery 1.6 for modifying checked properties of the form elements, `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`, `checked` is a property and setting false/true through `attr` doesn't change the `checked` property of radio buttons.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', function(i, checked){
       return !checked;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on Chrome (I haven't tested elsewhere - sorry).

```
$("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
```

The `.prop` function only got rid of the first instance for a radio group whereas the `removeattr` nuked the lot.